# How to handle lots of file downloads from my linux server

Tags: linux, hosting

I have a file 50MB file hosted in my deticated linux server, each day there is almost 50K users that download this file (2.5GB a day).

There are lots of crashes and users reports that sometimes even the file can't be downloaded since the server is overload.

I wonder if someone can help me how do I calculate which server/bandwidth/anything I need to handle that?

Is there any solution where I can host the file and pay per download?

Is there any setting or anything that I can improve or do on my server that will help to fix this issue?

My current server specification is:

```
2 x Intel Xeon E5 2620V2
2 x (6 x 2.10 GHz)
128 GB REG ECC
256GB SSD HD
1 IP Address
1 Gbit/s port Shared Bandwidth
```

I'll appreciate any help from you guys.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Find bottleneck in your system:

1) check application logs (nginx, apache...)

2) check system logs (syslog, messages, dmesg...)

3) use system utility for analyze system resources - disks load, memory, cpu, network (top, netstat, vmstat...)

When you find bottleneck, you can fix issues and increase num of downloads.

PS: also you can find system administrator, who can help you.